# im new to flutter , can you help please

Tags: android, flutter, version

I want to upload a new version of the application

this is my pubspec.yaml

version: 1.0.0+1

i dont now how to make it
should i change it to ???

version: 1.0.1+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version in flutter apps tries to follow the software versioning system, this means:

major.minor.patch+build

So if you are on major = 2, minor = 0, patch=13 and build = 4, it would be: 2.0.13+4

Now, the semantics for this are:

MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes.
MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards compatible manner.
PATCH version when you make backwards compatible bug fixes.

https://semver.org/

And build is for different compilations for a single code base, that could be that you are ready to upload your application and found out about a bug, then you do the cahnge and only increase the build number.